# T4 "header guard" for included files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-generation, t4

I'm trying to write some nice and structured t4 for code generation. I decompose my logic into reusable functions and put them into separate files (just like "normal" code). The problem is I cannot include a common file since it will be included multiple times.

For example, I have files 4 files: `Core.tt`, `File1.tt`, `File2.tt` and `MainTemplate.tt`.
`Core.tt` is inclued in both `File1.tt` and `File2.tt`. 
While `File1.tt` and `File2.tt` are included in `MainTemplate.tt`

When I want to generate output from `MainTemplate.tt` I get the following error:

```
Error   8   Compiling transformation: The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating62CD98C8FF0EB737CAFBD5ED17A158C3.GeneratedTextTransformation' already contains a definition for 'PropertyAttribute'
```

I guess, the reason is that `Core.tt` has been included twice. Is there a workaround for my problem? In c++ It's possible to add header guards: `#ifndef xxx #define xxx #endif`

Comment: It took me under 2 hours to write an equivalent to T4 which solves both this problem, and the problem of retransforming all dependent templates when a library template changes. T4 is not designed well. Don't use it.

Comment: @Jack: would you mind contributing to T4 project then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I've not been able to work out a way to get this to work, as there are hard limitations about where you can use #define in C#, and the #include comes in too late in the code.

Your best bet at this point is to log a feature request on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com and try to drum up some support.

Personally, I'd love to get this feature into the product.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this feature is built in to the T4 system.

[The T4 'include' directive supports a 'once' attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg586949.aspx), which should ensure a template is only included once, preventing duplicates.

Example:

```
<#@ include file="filePath.tt" once="true" #>
```

Comment: It's a great idea! But for some reason I am getting error at compile time: "Unexpected attribute: once". I include file like this: "<#@ include file="BaseCodegenTemplate.tt" once="true" #>". Do you know why is that can be?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 and T4 Toolbox for Visual Studio 14.0.0.76.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem with the following error message:

```
Compiling transformation: The type 'GeneratedTextTransformation' already contains a definition for 'BaseCodegenTemplate'
```

I searched my project with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> for this line of text:

```
<#@ include file="BaseCodegenTemplate.tt" #>
```

and found 2 occurrences of this line in 2 different files. After I removed one of the occurrences from one of the files the error disappeared.

But because include statement for BaseCodegenTemplate.tt file now is missing in that file, some code in that file is highlighted with red color because type definitions contained in BaseCodegenTemplate.tt are missing. But the overall code compiles well: types defined in BaseCodegenTemplate.tt are included during the build because BaseCodegenTemplate.tt is referenced in another file.